# C# Drag and Drop - Muliple Pictures Box to Panel or Flow layout panel

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I'm currently implementing drag & drop function in C# Window Forms. I've created multiple pictures box on left navigation, so user can drag and drop to right side panel.

But it does look like pictures box can not drop to the panel directly.
When i compile, it runs. But, when I drag and drop it makes following error:

```
"unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Panel' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox'."
```

Please suggest how can i make drag and drop "picutre 1, 2, 3" to the panel accordingly.?

```
    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox4.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(pictureBox4_DragEnter);
        pictureBox4.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(pictureBox4_DragDrop);
        pictureBox4.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(pictureBox4_MouseDown);

        panel2.AllowDrop = true;
    }

    private void pictureBox4_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
        pb.Image = (Image)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
    }

    private void pictureBox4_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
        pb.Select();
        pb.DoDragDrop(pb.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        panel1.Show();
    }

    private void panel2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
        pb.Image = (Image)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);

    }

    private void panel2_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;

        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }
```

Comment: On which line did you get the exception?

Comment: Change `pb.DoDragDrop(pb.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);` to `pb.DoDragDrop(pb, DragDropEffects.Copy);`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose in this code your sender is actually a Panel. Check it's type in the debugger:

```
private void panel2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
    pb.Image = (Image)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);

}
```

As a good principle always do typecasting like this:

```
PictureBox pb = sender as PictureBox; // will give you null if it can't be cast to PictureBox
if(pb != null)
{
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, however, casting error is gone, because it is "pb" is null. Sender is picturebox, but it will place into Panel..so i can put muliple pictures boxes to Panel.. did i make wrong approach.?

Comment: If pb is null then the sender is not a PictureBox. It's the panel. The panel sends you the DragDrop message, because that is where you are dropping your picture box.In MouseDown event save the picture box that you are dragging, using class property. Then in DragDrop use that property to get the image.